# Switching between nested while loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm new to Python and I was wondering if I could get some help. I think everything is working, except for it outputing `Guess higher/lower` prompt and then printing out `Enter a number:` instead of asking for the second `Guess higher/lower` prompt. I want it to say the second Guess prompt, not `Enter a number:` I hope that's explained well enough. If not, I will update it.

```
from random import randint
N=randint(0,100)
i=1000
a=0
n=int(N)
while i!=n:
  I=int(input('Enter a number: '))
  i=int(I)
  a=a+1
  while i>n:
    i=int(input('Guess lower: '))
    a=a+1
  while i<n:
    i=int(input('Guess Higher: '))
    a=a+1
  while i==n:
    print('Correct')
    print('You took',a,'attempts.')
    break
```

Comment: Consider using simple `if` instead of `while` and just simply tell user that their response was high or low.  Also the loop should be exited after the correct answer and then simply just print out the conclusion on the top level and the script will simply terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour that you want is not a work for `while` loops. While loops are used for iteratively executing a piece of code until a condition is met. While, stricly speaking, this is true for your code, the nesting that you have implemented and the overall structure of your code is not correct.

It would be much better if you used `if` and `else` statements. These are used for deciding about something and, based on whether it is true or false, executing a piece of code. If you think about it, this is exactly the inherent nature of the problem you are trying to solve. The code would look something like this:

```
from random import randint
N=randint(0,100)
i=1000
a=0
n=int(N)

#Ask for initial input
i=int(input('Enter a number: '))
a=a+1

#Start loop that loops until i == n
while i!=n:
  if i>n:
    i=int(input('Guess lower: '))
    a=a+1
  elif i<n:
    i=int(input('Guess Higher: '))
    a=a+1
  else:
    print('Correct')
    print('You took',a,'attempts.')
```

If you are woindering about the `elif`, it is a statement that gets executed if the if statement is not true and if the condition following elif is true. You can have multiple elif's. Have a look at any beginner tutorial to learn more.

Comment: This answer is a big improvement over the OP. I personally would continue refactoring, so I'm going to go ahead and post a separate answer.

Comment: @RobertB Yes, you are right that there is still some refactoring to do, I did not go that way to keep the "old way" appearance as much as possible so as the OP can see clearly what was the logic-breaking part.

Comment: I like that. I posted a separate answer so that both would be available. your answer is probably more appropriate now as he learns the language basics, but I thought it would be nice to also take it to the next step so that he can see that too. Also so other readers would have it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself) whenever you see duplication. Also, no need to comment obvious things.

1. First thing to notice is that there are things you are doing over and over like `a=a+1` and `input`. Try not to repeat yourself.
2. The second thing to notice, is that in every loop the only thing that changes is the prompt. Try to isolate that change.
3. Last thing is to know is how `while` loops work. You only have one loop, so you only need 1 while. So the loop will stop when `i == n` and thus that is the only time that "Correct" will print.

My final code:

```
from random import randint

a = 0
i = -1
n = randint(0, 100)
prompt = "Enter a number: "

while i != n:
    a += 1
    i=int(input(prompt))
    if i > n:
        prompt = 'Guess Lower: '
    elif i < n:
        prompt = 'Guess Higher: '
print('Correct')
print('You took {} attempts.'.format(a))
```